# Does cudaDeviceSynchronize() stop working when there are other jobs running on the gpu?

Tags: cuda

There are jobs running on the GPU, and if I run another code on top of it, the code stops at the point of cudaDeviceSynchronize(). Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently only one process is allowed to use a GPU at a given point in time. There is no fairness nor quantum to kill a ''job'' in case it runs for hours in a GPU. The basic usage is first come first serve.

But you may use the CUDA Multi-Process Service (MPS). It basically allows multiple processes to share a single gpu

https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf